# Enforce immediate typeclass instance resolution

Tags: coq, typeclass

Is there a way to enforce that when a typeclass is used, a particular instance is immediately found?

Right, now I'm getting an existential variable when there is no instance available, but I want to get an error.

A simple example will explain much better what I'm trying to achieve. I'm trying to get a function evaluation with implicit casting for certain types. In this case I want to have only one possible implicit cast `X' -> X`.

```
Class Evaluation (A B C : Type) : Type :=
  {
    cast_eval : (A -> B) -> C -> B
  }.

Instance DirectEvaluation (A B : Type) : Evaluation A B A :=
  {
    cast_eval := fun f x => f x
  }.

Parameter (X X' X'' Y : Type) (f : X -> Y) (x : X) (x' : X') (x'' : X'') (x_cast : X' -> X).

Instance XDashEvaluation : Evaluation X Y X' :=
  {
    cast_eval := fun ff xx => f (x_cast xx)
  }.

Compute (cast_eval f x).   (* f x *)
Compute (cast_eval f x').  (* f (x_cast x') *)
Compute (cast_eval f x''). (* (let (cast_eval) := ?Evaluation in cast_eval) f x'' *)
```

Is there a way to get an error when calling `(cast_eval f x'')`?

Comment: You can use an older version of Coq where `Compute` does not support evars :-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to get an error would be make a `Definition` first:

```
Definition e := cast_eval f x''.
Compute e.
```